# Is it possible to define this type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a TypeScript application.
My idea is to pass a type of features to my app.
Each feature is a class but it's not instantiated yet.
There is also a special method "init" in my application where I want to pass the real feature objects.

How to define this?

If I define my generic type like:

```
Application<F extends Record<string, Feature>>
```

Then TS wants me to pass instances to my type.
How can I define that this type is a record of classes and after that will I be able to create a new type which will reflect the structure of original type but with instances?

Answer (score 3):

To pass in a class you need to pass in the constructor of the class. You can do this using a constructor signature (similar to a function signature, just with the keyword `new` in front of it)

```
class Application<F extends Record<string, new () => Feature>> {
  
  constructor(feautures: F) {
    for(let key in feautures) {
      let f= new feautures[key]();
      f.init()
    }
  }
}


new Application({
  FeatureA,
  FeatureB
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEBiBTCAXArgJ0bA3sWsAlgHaEoAUAlLsPrAL7COiQwLLpYCCsiAHikTEAJnCSpM2HI3DQxHSQCFeAoaPYSsuZrLZcADvrCEQqQgHtiAHngrBIuACVEIcxmFWoKDCQDmAGlhiRAB3WCpYAF4APg1ORGjYvAI6V2IvDDQQFDdyADNkNHioAC4EamSCWDzcsEQUWABrRABPImJqwuKKuirYOoa8yKDQzogiySgAbWaWgF0qAG5eqryAOhIyKhXGAkZmYLCDIxMzS3JK8XiufzorpSZKIA)

Or if you want to have easier access to the instance types you could also use:

```
class Application<F extends Record<string, Feature>> {
  featureInstances: F;  
  constructor(feautures: { [P in keyof F]: new () => F[P] }) {
    this.featureInstances = {} as F
    for(let key in feautures) {
      let f= new feautures[key]();
      f.init()
      this.featureInstances[key] = f
    }
  }
}

let app = new Application({
  FeatureA,
  FeatureB
})
app.featureInstances.FeatureA.methodA();
app.featureInstances.FeatureB.methodB();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEBiBTCAXArgJ0bA3sWsAlgHaEoAUAlLsPrAL7COiQwLLpYCCsiAHikTEAJnCSpM2HLAC2iFAAsA9sK5Vc9RuGhiOkgEK8BQ0ewlZcs+cuH71OTbW1suAB1dhCIVISXEAPPBGgiJwAEqIIEoYwv5QKBgkAOYANGaciAB8mTQEAGZ6WACSxPEQxCCIUABcCADcBHRRpQloICjR5AUQaBk1lgDaAApExLAA1ogAnkp5CAC6tcSIAO6w6gC8OfDD8wzUeAQEioRQAHTdGSVlFVWwGxqw0Ah0+Z1g8hPTo7DdvZJQA6vI4fFC-B7LNZ-PoDSZTeZUOrA-JnEhkKjI2Anc6XSTXFDlSpQWHTPYPPLAxgERjMUFPdz3WCQ2BuDxeHx+ciHdKSLgpOjiDL6JiUYAQdwXQqIfGEqpnQW8s5yRQqNSUJHi1yS8zSlqy84KrD6JXWFR2dVAA)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to pass feature in a standalone method? The problem is that I have cycle dependency cause App is not initialized when I import it.